# Which docker image to use for running a private Stellar network with 3 nodes?

Tags: docker, private-network

I'm trying to run a private Stellar network with 3 nodes, each also running horizon. There are 2 docker images which seem to be useful for my case, but I don't know which one to use.

The first one is the [quickstart image](https://hub.docker.com/r/stellar/quickstart) but it seems that it's not a full functioning version as indicated in the readme:

> This image provide a default, non-validating, ephemeral configuration that should work for most developers.

The second image is the [base image](https://hub.docker.com/r/stellar/base). This image only contains the core and I have to run horizon and postgres in separate containers.

I was wondering which image is a better choice to start a private network.